# Angular MatDrawer with SIDE size dynamic

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem with a classic SideNav component with expandable mode (Angular 14).

I want to replicate the NetBox Layout with the Pin mode too (admin/admin).

```
https://demo.netbox.dev/
```

When the Sidenav is in its shrink mode with only icons, I need an "over" mode onMouseOver.
Then it must return in "side" mode onmouseout.

When I "pin" the menu, it has to keep the "side" mode with the full text of menu items.

As you can seen from example, there is a problem of spacing.

This is a simple example of the problem:

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-sidenav-example-dejcwd?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting isShowing to false and the right after setting `side_mode = 'side'` without revalidating the UI, as a result, the sidenav is calculating the dimensions based on the open state.

Running change detection will re-render the UI and the sidenav will calculate the correct with

```js
constructor(public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

mouseleave() {
  if (!this.isExpanded) {
    this.isShowing = false;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.side_mode = 'side';
  }
}
```